# What is the intuition for the limited variation in potential energy for HMC?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, hamiltonian-monte-carlo

In *A General Metric for Riemannian Manifold Hamiltonian Monte Carlo* (Betancourt, 2013), the author writes:

> The first [5] and still most common choice of the conditional density, $\pi(p|q)$, is a standard gaussian, [...]. This choice, however, ultimately limits the effectiveness of HMC when applied to intricate target distributions. Because $p^T M^{-1} p$ is a $\chi^2$ variate, in equilibrium $\Delta T \approx \frac{N}{2}$ and, with the Hamiltonian conserved along each trajectory, this implies that the variation in the potential is also limited to $\Delta V \approx \frac{N}{2}$.

I am struggling to understand why $p^T M^{-1} p$ being $\chi^2$ in equilibrium gives us that $\Delta T \approx \frac{N}{2}$. Further, I am also not entirely sure what the quantity $\Delta T$ represents in this context.

Where does this conclusion come from and what intuition is trying to be conveyed?